# Loop through SQL query result and compare against table values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Client_Programs) which contains a list of clients and a government program they're enrolled in.  Each client is identified by a unique ClientULink and programs have a ProgramULink. Each entry contains a StartDate and EndDate.  So the data may look like this:

```
ClientULink                             ProgramULink                            StartDate                    EndDate
b0afd171-28d0-48a3-989f-f2b0583c0fxx    46dcdf26-4916-4966-ac81-eaf57c7a26xx    2/2/2017 6:00:00 AM 5/2/2017 6:00:00 AM
```

A client can be in this table multiple times for the same (or different) programs. I'm being asked to create a query (report) of any client that has NOT re-enrolled into a program.  My thinking is to initially start off by running a query to return entries from the Client_Program table between two EndDates (which would be an input parameter in my final stored procedure for this report).  For example:

```
SELECT ClientULink, ProgramULink, StartDate, EndDate FROM Client_Program cp WHERE cast(cp.EndDate as date) BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30'
```

However, I would like to place these into a temp table or memory so that I can then loop through them and check all of these results against the main Client_Program table to see if these clients have any "newer" entries that shows they are re-enrolled or not.

```
SELECT ClientULink, ProgramULink, StartDate, EndDate FROM Client_Program cp WHERE ClientULink = 'b0afd171-28d0-48a3-989f-f2b0583c0fxx' AND cp.ProgramULink = '46dcdf26-4916-4966-ac81-eaf57c7a26xx' AND CAST(cp.StartDate as DATE) > '2017-05-30'
```

My question is how do I loop through my first results query?  Basically, I'm trying to find any client who has not re-enrolled (doesn't have an entry with a newer StartDate for a program - or specific program as shown in my query) than the EndDate range specified.

Any help in showing this in a stored procedure or query would be very much appreciated and helpful.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't get it.  Your query has a date range but nothing in the question suggests that a date range is needed.

Comment: It is a bit confusing to me.  They are asking to know any client who has not re-enrolled in a program (i.e. let existing program lapse).  So they EndDate is required, but am I using it correctly?  I felt that I'd allow the user to choose a date range (like last month) and then find ONLY those clients who had a program ending during that time.  THEN find if they re-enrolled or not.  This limited me to using the results from the date range query and not the entire Client_Program table - which is huge!  Make sense?  Thanks again.

Comment: If EndDate is required, why not use IS NOT NULL instead of a range? If you are only looking for re-enrollments and not new enrollments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `cursor` to do loops, but that is a poorly performaning option compared to a set based operation.

Using `not exists()` to return all clients in programs that ended in May, that have not re-enrolled:

```
select 
    ClientULink
  , ProgramULink
  , StartDate
  , EndDate 
from Client_Program cp 
where cp.EndDate >= '20170501'
  and cp.EndDate <  '20170601'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from Client_Program i
    where i.ClientULink = cp.ClientULink
      and i.ProgramULink = cp.ProgramULink
      and i.StartDate >= cp.EndDate
      )
```

Notes:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Should I use `not in()`, `outer apply()`, `left outer join`, `except`, or `not exists()`? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)
- The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

---

test setup:

```
create table Client_Program (ClientULink uniqueidentifier, ProgramULink uniqueidentifier, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
insert into Client_Program values 
 ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','2017-02-02T06:00:00','2017-05-02T06:00:00')
,('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','2017-02-02T06:00:00','2017-05-02T06:00:00')
,('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','2017-05-02T06:00:00','2017-08-02T06:00:00')
select 
    ClientULink
  , ProgramULink
  , StartDate = convert(char(10),StartDate,120)
  , EndDate   = convert(char(10),EndDate,120)
from Client_Program cp 
where cp.EndDate >= '20170501'
  and cp.EndDate <  '20170601'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from Client_Program i
    where i.ClientULink = cp.ClientULink
      and i.ProgramULink = cp.ProgramULink
      and i.StartDate >= cp.EndDate
      )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LYE54567

returns:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|             ClientULink              |             ProgramULink             | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 2017-02-02 | 2017-05-02 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

---

You could also use aggregation and filter in the `having` clause where `max(EndDate)` is between some date range (If they re-enrolled, then their `max(EndDate)` would not be in the date range):

```
select 
    ClientULink
  , ProgramULink
from Client_Program cp 
group by   
    ClientULink
  , ProgramULink
having max(EndDate)>= '20170501'
   and max(EndDate) < '20170601'
```

returns:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|             ClientULink              |             ProgramULink             |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure your not Aaron Bertrand in disguise?  You're definitely well read on his material; and quick to site it! :P

Comment: @xQbert I've never even been to Rhode Island.Though working for SentryOne would probably be awesome, considering the pub. https://www.sentryone.com/company/about-us#prettyPhoto

Comment: I need to loosen up a bit... pub anyone?  Set that SQL mind free...  and read some more ---- below

Comment: @xQbert Here is a good index of some of his bad habits articles: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival/.

Comment: @xQbert Oh, here is another article that is slightly related to my answer: - [Should I use `not in()`, `outer apply()`, `left outer join`, `except`, or `not exists()`? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: Hi Aaron... nice to meet you. :P  soo much good quality content to read.

Comment: @xQbert Good to meet... ahh you almost got me.

Comment: ohhhh.... you're just trying to distract me from answering more SO questions aren't you.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand this query, it is providing me the clients that have indeed re-enrolled into a program again.  Is there a way to provide which ones have NOT re-enrolled.  In other words - they do NOT have a StartDate >= EndDate?

Comment: @DataCrypt This returns clients that have not re-enrolled in programs where the enrollment that ends within the date range. I have added a demo to my answer to illustrate.

Comment: @SqlZim - Thank you very much!  I was able to use your query with a small change to the date handling and got it to work.  I appreciate your time and assistance in helping me with this.  Kindest regards.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you are looping in SQL, you're *probably* doing it wrong. You can use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) to achieve this.

```
SELECT ClientULink
FROM Client_Program 
WHERE CAST(EndDate as date) BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30'
EXCEPT
SELECT ClientULink
FROM Client_Program
WHERE CAST(StartDate as date) > '2017-05-01'
```

**Edit:** If a client Starts and Ends within the DateRange they will be wrongly excluded from the result.

Comment: If somebody was only once enrolled at e.g. '2017-05-05`, your query will not provide his name. It includes the name in the first part, but deletes it in the EXCEPT query. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you are not over-thinking this? Not re-enrolled appears to be the set of IDs (client, program) that have a count of 1. E.g.,

```
select cp.ClientULink, cp.ProgramULink from dbo.Client_Program as cp 
group by cp.ClientULink, cp.ProgramULink 
having count(*) = 1
order by cp.ClientULink, cp.ProgramULink ;
```

What else do you need?

Comment: No, but I see what you mean.  Not being enrolled means they're not currently in a program (which lasts between a StartDate and EndDate).  So, a client can be in a program from say 2/1/2016 through 2/1/2017.  They are sent a notice that it's expiring and to re-enroll about a month ahead of time.  If they do, they'd get a new record showing something like 3/1/2017 through 3/1/2018.  However, now they are asking me for a query to know who didn't re-enroll. So they don't have anymore records after their most recent program expired.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the date filter, try something like this:

```
select ClientULink, ProgramULink, StartDate, EndDate
from Client_Program cp
inner join
(
    select ClientULink, ProgramULink, count(*) as Count
    from Client_Program cp2
    group by ClientULink, ProgramULink
    having count(*) = 1
) cp2
on cp.ClientULink = cp2.ClientULink
and cp.ProgramULink = cp2.ProgramULink
where cast(cp.EndDate as date) between '2017-05-01' and '2017-05-30'
```